# LinearSolve linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I am new in Wolfram and dont understand how to solve equations with LinearSolve.  I have used simple Solve, but what do I need to do with LinearSolve?

```
Solve [{2x + 5y+8 == 0,4x - 7y - 10 == 0},{x,y}]
Solve [{34x + 78y-3 == 0,17x + 81y  == 65},{x,y}]
Solve [{47x - 22y +134 == 0,72x + 57y +99  == 0},{x,y}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `LinearSolve` which solves $A x = b$ do

```
ClearAll[x,y];
vars = {x, y};
eqs = {2 x + 5 y + 8 == 0, 4 x - 7 y - 10 == 0};
{b, A} = CoefficientArrays[eqs, vars];
LinearSolve[A, -b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
Solve[eqs, vars]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do the same for the other equations.

Comment: Seems good. Thank you. Will accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: To all and @meximah : I think this should be in the docs for `LinearSolve`, not just in the docs for [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html) (see under "Applications"). As this Q&A shows, `LinearSolve` is a natural place for the question to come up.